# Hiding OS X Sierra Dock Icons from files

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

I know with Mac OS X Versions lower then Sierra, you can edit the `Info.plist` file and add:

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

Right above this:

```
</dict>
</plist>
```

If I do this in Sierra, the app won't run. Has anyone figured out how to hide a *running* application from the dock?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in your own application, or another existing application?

Comment: I made a new Mac app in Xcode, and added the key "LSUIElement" = `<true/>` to its Info.plist.  The application runs, and the icon is not added to the dock.  Do you have a sample project that exhibits the bug?

Comment: @Ssswift hmm, [Koala](http://koala-app.com) brings an error saying it won't open when I try

Comment: Likely a result of System Integrity Protection: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the following and it worked

```
<key>LSBackgroundOnly</key>
<string>YES</string>
```

Comment: Wow! why not getting upvotes here? Everyone should upvote him!